# C# Is there a quick way (perhaps some Linq func) to find if every Card in an array of Card types share the same card value?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have a an array `Card [] cards` of the type `Card`, which has an int property `CardValue`:

```
public class Card
{
    public int CardValue { get; set; }
    // Other properties omitted.
}
```

How can I check if ALL the cards in the array have the same CardValue in a quick way?

Comment: be careful with the word quick. Quickly written down and quickly executed are different things. LINQ is more the first one.

Comment: Related: [How to check if all list items have the same value and return it, or return an “otherValue” if they don’t?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4390406/3744182).  You would need to insert a `.Select(c => c.CardValue)` to check that just the card values are equal.

Comment: *In addition, does somebody have a good and simple toutorial for Linq?* - requests to recommend off-site resources are [off-topic for stack overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251134).

Comment: If you can guarantee that the array is not empty, you can do `int first = cards[0].CardValue; bool allTheSame = cards.All(c => c.CardValue == first);`

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to process an array is via `for` and indexing into it, so:

```
public static bool SameCardValue(Card[] cards) {
    var firstCardValue = cards[0].CardValue;
    for (int j1 = 1; j1 < cards.Length; ++j1)
        if (cards[j1].CardValue != firstCardValue)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

I assume your `Card[]` won't be zero-length, though you could add a test for that case.

Answer (score -1):

You can e.g. do something like this:

`var allTheSame = Cards.Select(card => card.CardValue).Distinct().Count() == 1;`