# Determine if nested object property in a list is equal

Tags: c#

I have two classes, Property and Manager.

```
public class Property
{
    public Manager Manager {get;set;}
}

public class Manager {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Fullname {get; set;}
}

Property p1 = new  Property{
    Manager = new Manager {
        ID = 1,
        Fullname = "John  Doe"
    }
}

Property p2 = new  Property{
    Manager = new Manager {
        ID = 1,
        Fullname = "John  Doe"
    }
}

Property p3 = new  Property{
    Manager = new Manager {
        ID = 2,
        Fullname = "John  Doe"
    }
}

List<Property> properties = new List{ p1, p2, p3 }
```

In this `List` of `properties`, how can I determine that each property has the same Manager `ID`? If one or more don't, then I want to return `false`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390406/how-to-check-if-all-list-items-have-the-same-value-and-return-it-or-return-an

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if all list items have the same value and return it, or return an “otherValue” if they don’t?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390406/how-to-check-if-all-list-items-have-the-same-value-and-return-it-or-return-an)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a bit of `System.Linq` to determine if `All` items have the same `Id` as the `First` item:

```
bool allHaveSameId = properties.All(p => p.Manager.ID == properties.First().Manager.ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just override the Equals in both property and Manager

```
public class Manager{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Fullname {get; set;}

    public override bool Equals(Manager that){
        if ((obj == null) || ! this.GetType().Equals(obj.GetType())){
            return false;
        }else {
            return this.ID == that.ID;
        }
    }
}

public class Property{
    public Manager Manager {get;set;}

    public override bool Equals(Property that){
        if ((obj == null) || ! this.GetType().Equals(obj.GetType())){
            return false;
        }else {
            return this.manager.Equals(that.Manager);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @CaiusJard Wouldn't Manager Manager cause error? I have yet to test that. Since Manager is an object type now

Comment: No, that wouldn't cause an error, it's quite common.

Comment: @CaiusJard and Rufus Thanks for the clarification and notifying!

Comment: Hah, I've just noticed how wonky SO's C# syntax highlighting is on this particular code block and the one in the question.. Interesting

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd go with something like that linked in the comment;

```
  return properties.Any() && properties.All(p=>p.Manager.ID == properties[0].Manager.Id);
```

Comment: why the `properties.Any() &&` ?

Comment: Stop it exploding if properties has zero elements; it relies on there being a properties[0]

Comment: Ah right! I'm already throwing exception earlier in my code to handle that situation. Thanks.

Comment: Always good to avoid throwing exceptions if possible; they're more expensive than simpler checks

Answer (score 0):

```
return properties.Select(p => p.Manager.ID).Distinct().Count() == 1;
```

Comment: I considered this, but ultimately rejected it because it requires every element to be evaluated. If there were a million properties, and the first two were different, it would be better to use a method that stops after it has checked the first two