# C# list of history items for a record, identify what exact variables changed in the records

Tags: c#, performance, linq

So I have a table that I track changes on with cdc in sql
I have a requirement to find what specific values in my object have changed in a given time.
When I get my history records its basically a list of all the same object from its point of time when it changed.
I need an efficient way to use this list to identify exactly what fields changed within the object

using linq I am doing this but I am just curious is there a better way?

```
  Value01Changed = auditHistory.Any(x => 
         x.AuditAction == "Insert" || 
         auditHistory.Any(y => y.Value01 != x.Value01)),
  Value02Changed = auditHistory.Any(x => 
         x.AuditAction == "Insert" || 
         auditHistory.Any(y => y.Value02 != x.Value02)),
   Value03Changed = auditHistory.Any(x => 
         x.AuditAction == "Insert" || 
         auditHistory.Any(y => y.Value03 != x.Value03)),
```

For clarity this solution works I just think it is expensive and in-efficient and am curious if there is a better way

Comment: I think you need `&&` instead of `||`

Comment: not really what the question is about, but what i am doing there is if the audit action is an insert then i will take all the variables in the object as being changed, or "||" if the audit action is an update check if each specific variable changed or stayed the same

Comment: @TimSchmelter || is correct because Insert means the value (as well as all values) was changed

Comment: A [mcve] would be great here to be able to refactor. Right now we'd have to get your code working and create some sample data to be able to demonstrate an alternative. You should provide all that when you ask.

Comment: @Aurelius - If your edit is an answer to your question then post it as such. We do not put answers in questions on this site. That's because future readers are looking for questions ***with answers that are marked as accepted***. You cannot mark the question as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Peter's and John Wu's answer i implemented the following in an extension method which has tidied up my code and improved performance

```
    var hasInserts = auditHistory.Any(x => x.AuditAction == "Insert");

    Value01Changed = auditHistory.HasPropertyChanges(x => x.Value01 , hasInserts);

    Value02Changed = auditHistory.HasPropertyChanges(x => x.Value02, hasInserts);

    public static class HasPropertyChanged
    {
        public static bool HasPropertyChanges(this IEnumerable<AuditRecord> list, Func<AuditRecord, object> func,bool hasInserts)
        {
            if(hasInserts) return true;
            return list.GroupBy(func).Count() > 1;                
        }
    }
```

Comment: Be warned that `Func<AuditRecord, object> func` will only group reference types by distinct instance.

Answer (score 2):

You could just do the check for an inserted item once, instead of once per value.

```
var itemWasInserted = auditHistory.Any(x => x.AuditAction == "Insert");

Value01Changed = itemWasInserted ||
         auditHistory.Any(x => auditHistory.Any(y => y.Value01 != x.Value01)),

Value01Changed = itemWasInserted || 
         auditHistory.Any(x => auditHistory.Any(y => y.Value02 != x.Value02)),

 //etc
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you are not making a round trip to the database for each and every `Any`. Pull the data into memory. That way you only hit the database once.

```
var list = auditHistory.ToList();
```

The simple way to determine if a property has any changes throughout is to `GroupBy`. This could perform slightly better since it only iterates the list once and uses a hash table to keep track of changes.

```
var value0changed = list.GroupBy( x => x.Value0 ).Count() > 1;
```

### Edit

After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390406/how-to-check-if-all-list-items-have-the-same-value-and-return-it-or-return-an) I'd actually recommend you write an extension method like this:

```
static public bool AllSame<T>(this Enumerable<T> source)
{
    var firstValue = source.First().Value;
    return source.All( x=> x.Value == firstValue );
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
var value0changed = list.AllSame();
```

This would be even more efficient.

Comment: Why is it marked as the solution? First, it's necessary to find a value which doesn't equal the target value (the value just after (or before) the time interval being sought): "var value0changed = list.GroupBy( x => x.Value0 != targetvalue).Count() > 1;". Second, it's not likely 'Count' is more efficient than 'Any' while 'Count' should check every record, but 'Any' should find the first matched record only. But it's dependent from auditHistory's structure and the answer can be true.

Comment: I would have marked both this and Peter's answer as the solution if I could as both were valid solutions and I have used the combination of both in my implementation. I chose this as my solution though because the main issue I had with my original solution was the .Any within a .Any and this groupby solution does basically the same thing and is way more readable since I only care if there is multiple different versions of the value in the list not about any specific TargetValue not matching like you added in your comment rotabor

Comment: "var value0changed = list.GroupBy( x => x.Value0 ).Count() > 1;" --> "var value0changed = list.Count(x => x.Value0) > 1;"

Answer (score -1):

It seems there is no better way if you use a feature like Temporal table.

If you will track changes manually, you can record them in form of (Field, New value, Timestamp) which will directly provide the required answer.